# what are the default synonyms created for APPS user with Oracle EBS configuration?

Tags: oracle-ebs

can you anyone help me to find out whether all HR tables (ex: "PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F")synonyms created for APPS user by default with the configuration. 
If no de we need to create it after the configuration manually ? 
Can you please let me know whether APPS user have public synonyms for all the FND tables (ex:FND_USER,FND_RESPONSIBILITY etc) by default with the configuration , or do we need to create in manually ?

Answer (score 0):

The APPS synonyms come by default with the EBS installation.
You should not create public synonyms. If you have a different user accessing EBS objects, better have it using the existing APPS synonyms by

```
alter session set current_schema=apps
```

or for convenience, create a logon trigger for your database user to execute this automatically.